# i18n extract does not create directories nor files in Symfony 

Tags: php, symfony1, internationalization, symfony-1.4

I am trying to set up the i18n behavior on Symfony 1.4.18. I have some i18n-friendly strings (using the two underscores) in my frontend layout. I tried to run the command below :

```
$ ./symfony i18n:extract frontend fr --auto-save
```

At first, symfony found 17 strings, but didn't build the path apps/frontend/i18n/fr/ nor the file inside : messages.xml.

I re-ran the command above, but this time Symfony did not find any string. I thought, if Symfony does not find new strings, it might save it somewhere, so I ran another command on my Linux, to find any occurrences on one of my i18n strings (Typically I have this string : ) :

```
$ grep "Freelance" $(find ./)
```

This command was launched at the root of my project, but unfortunately it didn't find any occurrences except the one in my layout.

I don't know what to do anymore to solve my problem.

PS : I hope my english isn't too bad, it's not my native language, but I try to do my best.

Comment: Have you checked the folder `apps/frontend/118n/fr` ? It might have a file called `messages.xml`.

Comment: Have you set ```i18n: true``` in your ```settings.yml``` file?

Comment: Also, do you or the ./symfony script have permissions to write to the ```frontend/i18n/``` folder?

Comment: I thought that Symfony was able to create the different directories in apps/frontend/. But it's not a big deal, I created the path : apps/frontend/i18n/fr/

I also checked my configuration in settings.yml, I think the important lines are the next following :
all:
  .settings:
    i18n: true
    standard_helpers: [I18N, Partial]

And I run the command to extract strings in messages.xml, but there is still no messages.xml in apps/frontend/i18n/fr/ even if I created the path.

Also, concerning the permissions, they are the same as in lib/model/doctrine/base/ where Symfony can build models easily

Comment: Could you paste the whole `settings.yml` in your question? Then paste the whole output given by the `i18n:extract` ? Have you looked for any files in your project like `messages.xml` ?

Comment: `apps/frontend/config/settings.yml` : [settings.yml](http://pastebin.com/fkSkh25c) I found this morning two "messages.xml" in the cache path (cache/frontend/prod/i18n/some_md5_fr/messages.xml) but nothing in apps/frontend/. It does not make any sense. And the output given by i18n:extract : [i18n:extract output](http://pastebin.com/zFbrLtXj)

Comment: By the way, the given output related to i18n:extract was performed after a `./symfony cc` to clear the messages.xml in cache. It's weird that `i18n:extract` still does not find any new strings.

Comment: What happens if you run this in your ```dev``` environment? You should not be generating *anything* in production - you should build in ```dev``` and then deploy to production.

Comment: I'm surely missing something but, isn't the environment linked to the used frontend page (typically `web/frontend_dev.php` or `web/frontend.php`) ? In this case it was saying that there was a `messages.xml` in `cache/frontend/prod/...` because I made a request on the `frontend.php`, but if I'm requesting `frontend_dev.php`, I find a messages.xml in `cache/frontend/dev/i18n/some_md5_en/messages.xml`

Comment: I just need to know you are running the ```i18n:extract``` commands on your ```dev``` machine, not the ```prod``` machine. It should rule out one possible factor in why it's not working.
EDIT: actually that probably means you are, if you have a frontend_dev.php file present on the machine.

Comment: I'd now suggest checking these options:

    1. clear the cache by deleting all the files in it, not using the ```cc``` command. Try ```i18n:extract``` again, and see if the files are created. Before refreshing the site in your browser, check the cache is still clear. Refresh in your browser, and check the cache for the ```some_md5_en``` files.

    2. Delve into the sfi18n/GetText classes and use some echo commands to see what filepaths are being used. Maybe you have some PHP module missing they need?

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I already tried to clear the cache with `rm * -rf` in cache/ and then performed i18n:extract. I saw that the cache isn't clear after running this command, but it is only configuration files. Then I refreshed my browser too, and noticed that it's at this moment that some_md5_en/messages.xml path is created.

I will try the second action you recommand. But I found something weird. I started a new project to test i18n:extract, it worked perfectly. My project is in its early days, so I'm wondering if it's not a waste of time to debug it, rather than copy it in a new structure.

Comment: Maybe the i18n component is not using the default catalogue XLIFF to save the data. Has somebody else worked on this code and messed with the syfmony libs maybe?

Comment: I am the only one to work on this project so far. I'll try to "echo-ing" the i18n class tomorrow to see what happens in here.

Comment: Have you tried to delete your symfony folder and download it again?

Comment: Yes, actually. I was on Sf-1.4.16, and changed it to Sf-1.4.18 yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add

```
messageSource: '%SF_APP_DIR%/i18n'
```

option to your i18n factory configuration.

And look for your `messages.xml` in `app_dir/i18n/your_culture`. Old `messages.xml` where at `vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfdoctrineplugin/i18n` in my case

Answer (score 0):

Try to set i18n source in factories.yml

Something like this:

```
  i18n:
  class: sfI18N
  param:
    source:               XLIFF
    debug:                false
    untranslated_prefix:  "[T]"
    untranslated_suffix:  "[/T]"
    cache:
      class: sfFileCache
      param:
        automatic_cleaning_factor: 0
        cache_dir:                 %SF_I18N_CACHE_DIR%
        lifetime:                  31556926
        prefix:                    %SF_APP_DIR%/i18n
```

[here](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories#chapter_05_i18n) you can find more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do this in your project root:

   ```
   sudo find . -print | grep -i 'messages.xml'
   ```
2. Then delete the file (s) you found (probably within sfDoctrinePlugin/i18n in the symfony vendor files)
3. Use the settings from above for your factory.yml and settings.yml
4. Restart task:

   ```
    php symfony i18n:extract frontend fr --auto-save
   ```

   That's all. Now the messages.xml is generated. Missing folders are created.
5. (Revert the chmod changes you did before)

Answer (score -1):

Your default language is *`fr`* and you're trying to get the translations to *`fr`*?

The  xml files should have the source string (in french - your default language) and target string (in english or whatever).

Try `./symfony i18n:extract frontend en --auto-save` (or whatever language you want, other than french) and let us know if you'll get what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately it didn't work. I ran `$ mkdir en` into `apps/frontend/i18n` and then your command (with the en location) but the en/messages.xml is not created.

Comment: Do you have anything (related to i18n) defined in you factories.yml?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm not used to edit this file, and I'm pretty sure this is the default one, but here is the copy : [apps/frontend/config/factories.yml](http://pastebin.com/N44HLBVS)